# Is it good practice to create an unused reference to the value returned by a called method?

Tags: java, coding-style

I have a friend whose teacher considers this good practice:

```
public void enterAnythingToContinue(){
    String junk = in.nextLine();
}
```

I googled this, but didn't find an explanation for it, though as expected there were other users of this method; mainly teachers.

Could it be that it doesn't matter if you do it or not, and that it's just a matter of clarity and pedagogy?

Even if you don't have a definite answer, any input is appreciated.

Comment: There is no point at all creating the junk variable here...

Comment: @fge is correct , if that is the last line .

Comment: This smell like `Scanner` never closed.. Also a good IDE tells you about `junk` being an unused variable

Comment: @RC. Yes, but `in` is an instance variable, so maybe the OP will close it later in some other method

Comment: She might be  thinking of assigning `null` to `junk` believing that it might enforce the JVM to gc the object read by `Scanner`..which is absolutely not needed here..Garbage Collector knows how to collect the garbage..

Comment: @RC Yeah this is only an example. I'd imagine that if this were in a text-based game, which is where I've seen it, you'd want to keep it open until it exits.

Comment: @Mac She didn't enforce that though, she just thought it were better assigning it to a String variable, even if the value was never to be used.

Comment: When I first read this I thought the question was pertaining to the amount of comments in that method, not the use of a junk variable.

Comment: Why not ask the teacher? After all they are there to teach.

Comment: @handuel I live in a different country, and he won't meet her because it's summer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could point to the ambivalence of methods in Java. You can use this method like this

```
String junk = in.nextLine();
```

or that

```
in.nextLine();
```

Maybe your teacher will emphasize on a "function" rather to a "procedure" (void return type).
If you assign a value the reader knows you are using a method that returns a value.

I don't see any advantage while you are using modern IDEs.

Comment: I'd say assigning a value to a variable that's not used will most likely confuse reader (*"Is there something missing here?"*), rather than yield any relevant information.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question.
Though I have another one: are there any disadvantages to this? I'd imagine that there isn't because it would be so miniscule.

Answer (score 5):

```
String junk = in.nextLine();
```

The variable name suggests that the teacher knows that the value isn't going to be used any more and hence is simply trying to emphasize that the method does return something. But, in all such cases instead of creating an unnecessary reference (and confusing the reader) prefer comments to make the intent clear.

```
in.nextLine(); // skipped
```

Comment: +1  Agreed.  As a minor side effect benefit, this style also gives you something to look at in the debugger.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in Visual Studio (for C# at least) you can see the result of this without having a junk assignment like this by looking at the "locals" tab which will store it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a reference to the returned from this call `in.nextLine();` object. The reference gets collected immediately after returning from method.

There is a point to do that only if you're planning to do something with it in the same method.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed.
But do you know why she 'forces' this practice on her students?

Comment: the only reason I can think of: it is education purpose - you should remember that this method returns sth. It is usually forgotten in cases where you remove element from collection (remove method returns the removed object)

Comment: Just a very tiny nit: the reference *becomes eligible for collection* immediately after returning from [the] method.  It won't actually get collected until the garbage collector runs.